# setTimeout is not working in firefox and working in chrome and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

See my code i am using settimeout in my code with 0 value, this same code is working fine in chrome and ie but it is not working in firefox.

```
setTimeout(function() {
              $("#closeButton").focus();
            }, 0);
```

when if i write this code like this then it's working in firefox why and how to fix this without this hack.

```
$("#closeButton").focus(); <-- by adding this code works but with out it not
setTimeout(function() {
                  $("#closeButton").focus();
                }, 0);
```

Regards,
Vinit PAtel

Comment: Are you sure you've got jQuery loaded? Have you tested the setTimeout with a `console.log`? It works in Firefox for me

Comment: If it works without the setTimeout, then why do you need the timeout at all?

Comment: What is not working actually? Are you getting any JS error msg in console? 
setTimeout should always work!

Comment: if you have the timeout set to 0 why are you using setTimeout? Just run the function?

Comment: My page is loaded and js also, and i am doing this because i am chang dynamically tabinxed of control so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case might be that your page on FF hasn't loaded yet.

Have you tried:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //code
});
```

And also try `window.setTimeout`.

But honestly I don't know the reason you have a setTimeout when it's set to 0.
It's basically you just executing the function. So why not just do that without the `setTimeout`?

Comment: yes i had tried with windows.setTimeout but not working

Comment: a `setTimeout` with 0 can be useful to make a piece of code execute after the current event has been processed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop